# Access a task, but don't click on take

Tags: task, bonita

I wonder if it is possible to perform a task when it becomes available to a user without the user having to click the "take" button. Because I have a process with many tasks and ends up being annoying to have to every time have to click on "take". If it can be done, it would be great if you could give me an example.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only one user can perform a task you can configure the `single actor` "actor filter" on the task (or on the lane). By doing so the task will be automatically assigner to the single user that can perform the task.

When using "actor" a user need to "take" the task in order to avoid concurrent actions from several different users that can actually do the task (candidates).